# dd: writing to Invalid argument with 4k blocksize on iSCSI LUN

Tags: dd, libvirt, iscsi

Why can't use `oflag=direct` on the 4k blocksize iSCSI disk?
**Could other applications also have a problem with the cause?**

```
root@testvm02:~# dd if=/root/speedtest of=/mnt/8k_512/speedtest oflag=direct
51200+0 records in
51200+0 records out
26214400 bytes (26 MB, 25 MiB) copied, 59,4312 s, 441 kB/s

root@testvm02:~# dd if=/root/speedtest of=/mnt/8k_4k/speedtest oflag=direct
dd: writing to '/mnt/8k_4k/speedtest': Invalid argument
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,000790648 s, 0,0 kB/s

root@testvm02:~# dd if=/root/speedtest of=/mnt/4k_4k/speedtest oflag=direct
dd: writing to '/mnt/4k_4k/speedtest': Invalid argument
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000139662 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

my environment @storage server:

```
/usr/sbin/zfs create -s -V 50GiB STORAGE01/4af1a9b7-0592-4707-a875-986d91fceac4 #<-- / & vda on testvm02
/usr/sbin/tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode logicalunit --tid 19 --lun 1 -b /dev/zvol/STORAGE01/4af1a9b7-0592-4707-a875-986d91fceac4
#
/usr/sbin/zfs create -s -V 50GiB STORAGE01/209afd7c-bdd6-4125-a899-b98758fcc6c0 #<-- /mnt/8k-512 & vdb on testvm02
/usr/sbin/tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode logicalunit --tid 19 --lun 2 -b /dev/zvol/STORAGE01/209afd7c-bdd6-4125-a899-b98758fcc6c0
#
/usr/sbin/zfs create -s -V 50GiB STORAGE01/6ae21fa3-df76-4843-ab65-0700af4f04f7 #<-- /mnt/8k-4k & vdc on testvm02
/usr/sbin/tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode logicalunit --tid 19 --blocksize 4096 --lun 3 -b /dev/zvol/STORAGE01/6ae21fa3-df76-4843-ab65-0700af4f04f7
#
/usr/sbin/zfs create -s -o volblocksize=4k -V 50GiB STORAGE01/24d38989-b47b-4e3c-b5ea-5d9a30d611f6 #<-- /mnt/4k-4k & vdd on testvm02
/usr/sbin/tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode logicalunit --tid 19 --blocksize 4096 --lun 4 -b /dev/zvol/STORAGE01/24d38989-b47b-4e3c-b5ea-5d9a30d611f6
#
# default zvol blocksize = 8k, default iSCSI LUN blocksize = 512
```

VM:

```
virt-install --name 'testvm02.domain.de' --description 'desc' --os-type 'Linux' --os-variant 'debian9' --ram 2048 --vcpus 2 --cdrom '/var/lib/libvirt/boot/firmware-10.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso' --graphics vnc,password=foobar --network 'bridge:br540,model=virtio,virtualport_type=openvswitch' --disk 'vol=c0dcc42e-7805-4ab3-845f-363bdedada5b/unit:0:0:1,logical_block_size=512,physical_block_size=512' --disk 'vol=c0dcc42e-7805-4ab3-845f-363bdedada5b/unit:0:0:2,logical_block_size=512,physical_block_size=512' --disk 'vol=c0dcc42e-7805-4ab3-845f-363bdedada5b/unit:0:0:3,logical_block_size=4096,physical_block_size=4096' --disk 'vol=c0dcc42e-7805-4ab3-845f-363bdedada5b/unit:0:0:4,logical_block_size=4096,physical_block_size=4096'
```

all disks formatted with ext4

```
root@testvm02:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x50172cb2

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *      2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       999424 104855551 103856128 49,5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/vdb: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5e831f4b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vdb1        2048 104855551 104853504  50G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/vdc: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 13107200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x791f5094

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vdc1         256 13106943 13106688  50G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/vdd: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 13107200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6de2b945

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vdd1         256 13106943 13106688  50G 83 Linux
```

Comment: What if you use `dd bs=4k ...` instead?

Comment: when i use `dd if=/root/speedtest of=/mnt/8k_4k/speedtest bs=4k oflag=direct` it works, Could other applications also have a problem with the cause? By changing the block size, I want to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't use `oflag=direct` on the 4k blocksize iSCSI disk?

You can use direct I/O, but bypassing kernel caches induces limitations that are mentioned in the [`open(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) manpage:

> The `O_DIRECT` flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os.In Linux alignment restrictions vary by filesystem and kernel version and might be absent entirely.
> (...)
> Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, the alignment of the user buffer, and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the filesystem.  Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size of the underlying storage (typically 512 bytes) suffices.  The logical block size can be determined using the [ioctl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) `BLKSSZGET` operation or from the shell using the command: `blockdev --getss`

To conclude, if you are using `oflag=direct` you must also set `bs` (or just `obs` here) to a multiple of the underlying block size. `bs` is 512 by default; so when your block size is 4096, you must set it to 4k, 8k, etc.

```
dd if=/root/speedtest of=/mnt/8k_4k/speedtest oflag=direct bs=4k
```